# unzipping a file in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have a zipped file, which i want to extract the contents of it. What is the exact procedure that i should do to achieve it. Is there any framework to unzip the files in cocoa framework or objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to unzip the file, I would recommend using `NSTask` to call unzip(1). It's probably smart to copy the file to a directory you control -- probably in /tmp -- before unzipping.

Comment: You don't control /tmp, anyone can write to it.

Comment: Graham: But it's a fine place to do temporary work to avoid clobbering an existing folder.

Comment: Use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` instead of `/tmp`, although be careful, it behaves a little more like `/var/tmp`. It will get cleaned out, but it is not always at a reboot.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on iOS or don't want to use `NSTask` or whatever, I recommend my library [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive).

Usage:

```
NSString *path = @"path_to_your_zip_file";
NSString *destination = @"path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_it_unzipped";
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

Pretty simple.

Comment: Can we use your library while submitting the app on the apple store ?

Comment: is it possible to zip folders aswell?

Answer (score 6):

On the Mac you can use the built in `unzip` command line tool using an `NSTask`:

```
- (void) unzip {
    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* zipPath = @"myFile.zip";

    NSString* targetFolder = @"/tmp/unzipped"; //this it the parent folder
                                               //where your zip's content 
                                               //goes to (must exist)

    //create a new empty folder (unzipping will fail if any
    //of the payload files already exist at the target location)
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:targetFolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                           attributes:nil error:NULL];


    //now create a unzip-task
    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:zipPath];
    NSTask *unzipTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [unzipTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/unzip"];
    [unzipTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:targetFolder];
    [unzipTask setArguments:arguments];
    [unzipTask launch];
    [unzipTask waitUntilExit]; //remove this to start the task concurrently

}
```

That is a quick and dirty solution. In real life you will probably want to do more error checking and have a look at the `unzip` [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/unzip.1.html) for fancy arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Swift 4 version similar to Sven Driemecker's answer.

```
func unzipFile(at sourcePath: String, to destinationPath: String) -> Bool {
    let process = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/bin/unzip", arguments: ["-o", sourcePath, "-d", destinationPath])
    process.waitUntilExit()
    return process.terminationStatus <= 1
}
```

This implementation returns a boolean that determines if the process was successful or not. Is considering the process successful even if warnings were encountered.

The return condition can be changed to `return process.terminationStatus == 0` to not even accept warnings.

See [unzip docs](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/unzip.1.asp) for more details on diagnostics.

You can also capture the output of the process using a `Pipe` instance.

```
func unzipFile(at sourcePath: String, to destinationPath: String) -> Bool {
    let process = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()

    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/unzip")
    process.arguments = ["-o", sourcePath, "-d", destinationPath]
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    do {
        try process.run()
    } catch {
        return false
    }

    let resultData = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let result = String (data: resultData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print(result)

    return process.terminationStatus <= 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more concise version based on codingFriend1's approach

```
+ (void)unzip {
    NSString *targetFolder = @"/tmp/unzipped";
    NSString* zipPath = @"/path/to/my.zip";
    NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/unzip" arguments:@[@"-o", zipPath, @"-d", targetFolder]];
    [task waitUntilExit];
}
```

**-d** specifies the destination directory, which will be created by unzip if not existent

**-o** tells unzip to overwrite existing files (but not to deleted outdated files, so be aware)

There's no error checking and stuff, but it's an easy and quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zip.framework](http://code.google.com/p/zip-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

`-openFile:` (`NSWorkspace`)  is the easiest way I know.